# Can I use stdin in conjunction with argv when using one python file piped into another?

Tags: python, input, mapreduce, stdin, argv

Basically I am running mapreduce so I'm going to pipe in to the reducer. What I'm having trouble with is how to specify a directory path which I will use with os.listdir to essentially get to and then compute all the files in that directory alone. But I know I only want what is in the last directory and not the sub-directories on that same level. I may consider also using fileinput().

I think I may be using stdin wrong here, depends on if it has to be from the command line or if it can be indirectly from the command line.

This was my command-line input: "./path1/path2/path3" ./map.py | sort | ./red.py

What I got as an error from doing what I want to do is -bash, not a directory ./pythonfile.py

Using Python 2.7.2

This is what I'm doing:

```
def func():
    path = sys.argv[0]
    return [filenames for filenames in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,filenames))]

if func() is not None: 
   for file in func():
       sys.stdin.read()
       ...etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"./path1/path2/path3" ./map.py | sort | ./red.py
```

That tells `bash` to execute the program `./path1/path2/path3` with the argument `./map.py`. This is almost certainly not what you want to do.

```
path = sys.argv[0]
```

This is the name of the *script* -- the first element of `argv[]` is, by convention, the name of the program that is being executed. See this:

```
$ cat echo.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print sys.argv[0]
$ chmod 755 echo.py
$ ./echo.py
./echo.py
$
```

Perhaps what you intended to do was `echo` the string to the script:

```
echo path1/path2/path3 | ./map.py | sort | ./red.py
```

But then you could not use the `argv[]` array to get at it easily. In fact, it is *very* difficult to properly parse multiple pathnames from a free-form input like this, so I'd avoid it entirely, and pass the names as *arguments*:

```
./map.py path1/path2/path3 /a/s/econd/pathname
```

You could iterate over all paths passed as arguments using something like this:

```
>>> a=["nothing", "passwd", "shadow"]
>>> [f for f in a[1:]]
['passwd', 'shadow']
>>> import os
>>> [f for f in a[1:] if os.path.isfile(f)]
['passwd', 'shadow']
>>>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the colon? Thanks, but I'm sure I essentially want to echo the path to the script, so how do I go about parsing multiple path names to reach my last directory full of files? I'm not sure I understand your example with tuples or lists, cause I won't know the filenames to pass in. As far as arguments, can I still utilize the pipe in the way I need to if I use it that way and are the arguments received the same way? Via stdin or argv?

Comment: Ah, the `[1:]` was to omit the first entry, since it is just the name of the script. (Not the path.) I've gotta run, but just consider that I used `a` for simple testing, your users will provide values via `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc..